# How to store serialized srray as user meta with ID?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WordPress, specifically WooCommerce, creating a new plugin to allow the user to store multiple shipping addresses. I'm currently storing these new shipping addresses as meta data in the user meta data table as a serialized array. I need a way to store these with some sort of ID.

What's the best way to do this -- give each a key ID with a unique number? Try to increment the last highest ID? Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep the serialized array but extend it to multidimensional?

```
array(
    0 => array(city => 'Dallas', state => 'TX'),
    1 => array(city => 'Madison', state => 'WI')
);
```